# Smooth video recording with RTMP (rtmplite and flash-VideoIO)

Tags: flash, video, video-streaming, flv, rtmp

I have a feature where users can record videos right from their browser. I'm using Flash-VideoIO (http://code.google.com/p/flash-videoio/) on the client, and rtmplite (http://code.google.com/p/rtmplite/) as my RTMP server hosted on Amazon EC2.

Everything works except for the fact that every FLV that rtmplite produces is very choppy and low quality. I know its possible to record smooth video even with a relatively slow connection as evidenced by this http://robo.to

Robo.to is a service that lets you record video from your browser. It's able to produce smooth and high quality video. How can I mimic this functionality with rtmplite and flash-videoIO? Is there a way to increase the buffer on the stream?